# How to switch entirely from pip to brew

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I have read elsewhere that brew is a better option than pip to install packages (and indeed I had less problems installing Python packages with brew than with pip). The problem is that when I run

```
brew update && brew outdated && brew upgrade --all
```

and then

```
pip-review -a
```

it seems like the same packages are installed twice (for example `matplotlib`, `scipy`, and the like).
How can I get rid of pip and switch entirely to brew, as to avoid double installations and potential conflicts?

Comment: Does this 'elsewhere' tell us how to do it?

Comment: PyPi is the standard package index that pip is hooked up to; brew packages typically have to be created and maintained specifically for brew. Is there a brew plugin to hook up directly to PyPi? Otherwise it would seem like an extremely inferior solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You cannot expect all python packages available via brew.

pip is the python package manager, having an understanding of how the python packages should be installed by querying a remote server of python packages called [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org).

Brew, on the other hand, is a general software installation system for your Mac. It is a project into existence only because Apple is lazy to provide a good package manager and package management system for installing Unix/ Mac software on Apple.
There are many Python packages which exist on brew as volunteers took the pain to convert it to [brew formulae](http://brewformulas.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bterm%5D=python&commit=Search). But it certainly does not guarantee of 100% 1-1 mapping of brew package to pip installable package.

Comment: Is the opinionated Apple-bashing necessary in this answer?

Comment: I don't know. I thought, it was required for me to state why brew exists in the first place. I am apple-fan-boy too and love their products!

Comment: There are many reasons which factor into the decision for or against providing, **maintaining and supporting** a package distribution system. "Laziness" is probably the least of Apple's reasons against doing so. Realistically speaking, it's better for everyone involved to have a 3rd party fill that gap than to have Apple provide a system which a) is probably of limited interest and use to them and therefore b) will mostly languish and probably be replaced by a 3rd party anyway.

Comment: Maybe someone could provide a consistency checker which would monitor the disk and say "here you have the same package installed twice, I suggest you de-pip it and brew it" or the opposite ("de-brew and pip it"). Every time I update both brew and pip I'm afraid that I will end up with incompatible configurations…

Comment: Note that it’s called “Homebrew”, `brew` is just its command.

Answer (score 0):

You still want to use `pip`, you just should be using Homebrew's copy of it, rather than some other variant. Homebrew's copy of pip is part of the `python` package, so if you `brew install python` you'll have `pip` all setup and ready to go.

To clean up any non-Homebrew-provided pip packages, just delete the folder the module is in directly. For example, if you manually installed `pip`, the modules are probably stored under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` somewhere.